# PHP hash() function returns same value for different input

Tags: php, html, forms, hash, registration

I'm taking my baby steps with setting up user registration for my website. I have a form like this

```
<form action="registrate-user.php" method="POST"> <br/>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""> <br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Secret"> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" value=""><br/>
    <input id="registratebutton" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

and a receiver like this

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $hashedpass = hash('md5', $password);

    echo $username . " " . $email . " " . $hashedpass;

?>
```

But the same value is echoed when I enter different passwords! Why is this?

Comment: Form elements must have a `name` attribute to be passed from the browser to the webserver.... so you're not getting anything passed as $_POST['password'].... so you're always hashing the same null value

Comment: Baby steps are good when learning, however using `md5` should be left alone. It's considered unsafe for password storage. Just a quick "FYI" ;-)

Comment: oh okay, I understand. Post it as an answer and I will accept it as a solution. @Fred-ii- which algorithm do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Have a read here >>> http://php.net/password and always `hash` not encrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $_POST array is filled with all the fields in a form that has the **name** attribute, not the **id**, and your password input hasn't one. You can confirm this by echoing the unencrypted password.

To solve your issue, just add **name="password"** like you did on the other fields.

```
<form action="registrate-user.php" method="POST"> <br/>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""> <br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Secret"> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value=""><br/>
    <input id="registratebutton" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Also take a look at the new [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function in PHP, it's better than MD5.